# OnTriggerEnter() is called right on the start

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making some sort of a Evolution simualtor game. I have a script that is supposed to destroy the GameObject it's attached to when a creature's CapsuleCollider Triggers the OnTriggerEnter().

I have a problem that even tho the Creature's collider isn't even close to the Food, it still destroys the GameObject.

My script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FoodEat : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject FoodGO;
    public Rigidbody FoodRB;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Creature)
    {
        Destroy(FoodGO);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        FoodRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        FoodGO = FoodRB.gameObject;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Rigidbody[] allRigidBodies = (Rigidbody[])FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Rigidbody));

        foreach (Rigidbody body in allRigidBodies)
        {
            if (body.gameObject.layer == 10)
            {
                 OnTriggerEnter(body.gameObject.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>());
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) is a monobehaviour lifecycle method. You should not call it from your own code; it will automatically be called when it detects collisions.

Furthermore, the logic in your code right now seems to be incorrect, it is...

> "Every frame, loop through all rigidbodies in the scene and if 1 is found on layer 10, destroy the FoodGO"

Simply remove your entire Update method and put an `if` in your Collision method, and it should work:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody), typeof(Collider))]
public class FoodEat : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter(collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log(other.gameObject.name + " on layer " + other.gameObject.layer);

        if (other.gameObject.layer == 10)
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

}
```

A few noteworthy edits of your code:

1. I removed FoodGO, since it's the GameObject this script is attached to, you can access it by just writing `gameObject` or `this.gameObject`.
2. I remove the Rigidbody reference since it is not used anymore, and thus the entire Start() method.
3. Since this code requires a Rigidbody and a Collider to work, I added a [RequireComponent] attribute in the top, which will make Unity tell you if you forgot to add those components on the object you attach this script to.
4. I added a Debug.Log that prints the name & the layer on the creature that collides with the food, so you can debug and make sure it is working as expected

Comment: But could I specify which collider I want to detect? For example only trigger on BoxCollider

Comment: I suppose you could try: `if (other.gameObject.layer == 10 && typeof(other) == typeof(BoxCollider))`. I've never done it myself, but I think it should work. Basically checking if the colliding component is of type BoxCollider

Comment: @VojtěchVach You can check layers, tags, gameobject name, the presence or absence of an attached component...whatever you want to check to insure that the right collision is detected: you have access to the entire GameObject via `other.gameObject`